# python :Function to return length of each element in list gives error

Tags: python

Please let me know the reason for the error in the code below.

```
def lenli(ab):

    results=[]
    for a in ab:
        results.append(len(a))
    return results
```

shows an error

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-8e23c7ef98a0> in <module>()
----> 1 lenli[ab]

TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

thanks
sindia

Comment: Your implementation is ok. You seem to be calling your function `function[ab]` whereas it should be `function(ab)`.

Comment: Also consider `ab_len = [len(a) for a in ab]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your function wrong. Square brackets `[]` are the shorthand for `__getitem__` (which `lenli` does not have). Parentheses `()` are the shorthand for `__call__`, which you want.

In short: type `lenli(ab)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the code you've shown, but in the code that calls it. Functions are called with parentheses, `()`, not square brackets.